# Openssl header version showing different after recomplie php

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

i am using cenots 6.7, also i upgraded my openssl version from 1.0.1e fips to 1.0.1g from source package. But upgrade process affected in apache and not in php. even i recompile php, Php still showing older version

Openssl header versions showing older version (1.0.1e fips)
openssl library version showing upgraded version (1.0.1g)

Could you please help to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler to link against your own OpenSSL instead of the system-provided one. I don't know how to exactly do this via normal OpenSSL build process though.